# Unwanted tag names in WCF Services

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a wcf service and I have class like below:

```
    public class Message
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "message")]
        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MsgID")]
        [DataMember(Name = "MsgID")]
        public string MsgID{ get; set; }
    }
```

Then i browsed my service in a browser the xml i am getting like below:

```
<MessageResponse>
    <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
    <a:Message>
      <a:message>msg1</a:message>
      <a:MsgID>1</a:MsgID>
     </a:Message>
</MessageResponse>
```

My Service Contract is Like below:
**and one more important thing is:MessageDco class is a copy of Message Class**

```
[ServiceContract()]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]    
    public class UserLoginProfileService
    {        
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetMessages?MsgID={MsgID}")]
        public MessageResponse GetMessage(Guid MsgID)
        {
            MessageResponse objMessageResponse = new MessageResponse();
            try
            {

                Message objMessage = new MessageFacade().GetMessage(MsgID);
                if (objUserLoginProfile != null)
                {
                    MessageResponse.Status = Status.Success;                   
                    MessageResponse.Messages = Mapper.ToDataContractObjects(Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    objMessageResponse.Status = Status.Success;                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                objMessageResponse.Status = Status.Failure;               

            }
            return objMessageResponse;
        }
    }

public class MessageResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Messages")]
          [DataMember(Name = "Messages")]
        public MessageDco[] Messages { get; set; }

          [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
          [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
          public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

My mapper class is like below:

```
public sealed class Mapper
    {
     public static MessageDco[] ToDataContractObjects(IEnumerable<MessageDco> objMessageDco)
    {
        if (objMessageDco != null)
        {
            return objMessageDco.Select(a => ToDataContractObjects(a)).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

if we see "a:" is added to the tags. why it is added? i am unable remove that "a:" from the tags. Please help me how to remove "a:" from Tags. And also if you see Status tag is coming correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "a" is the prefix that defines in which namespace the attribute message, status etc are declared.

Comment: Thanks For the reply Rajesh, But the Message class is in Different Namespace(not a) But still i am getting "a:" in the tags. How to remove it?

Comment: the reference to the namepsace would be in the root element of the compelte message. just try to inspect it with fiddler. Could you also show your service contract, for me have a better understanding and try to provide some solution

Comment: It's XML namespaces, not .NET namespaces. Leave it alone.

Comment: Hi Rajesh I edited the post and i also shown you the service contract. Please tell me if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Hi John, May be those are XML Namespaces, How can i Leave it. Because of the "a:" i am unable to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the DataContractSerializer you don't need the XmlElement attribute

Further more you should use a DataContract attribute on all classes and specify the namespaces, because they are defined implicitly if they are missing.  Different classes may have difference XML namespaces.

The MessageResponse object has a Messages array of MessageDco object but the sample XML supplied does not match, I would expect a **Messages** element containing a set of **Message** elements.